# Pandas EXCLUSIVE LEFT OUTER JOIN with line count

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join

I am creating a transactions import tool that updates a DB with new transactions every day.

I am getting an Excel file (*that I am opening using pandas*) with the entire month transactions and I am trying to filter only the new transactions by merging the new DataFrame with the existing one.

For this I am using pandas merge to do *EXCULSIVE LEFT OUTER JOIN* but I have a problem with multiple rows with the same exact values.

See this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[pd.Timestamp('2023-1-1'), 'A', 10]
                            , [pd.Timestamp('2023-1-1'), 'A', 10]
                            , [pd.Timestamp('2023-1-1'), 'B', 11]
                            , [pd.Timestamp('2023-1-2'), 'C', 12]
                            , [pd.Timestamp('2023-1-2'), 'D', 13]
                            , [pd.Timestamp('2023-1-2'), 'E', 14]
                            , [pd.Timestamp('2023-1-3'), 'F', 15]]),
                   columns=['Date', 'Title', 'Amount'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[pd.Timestamp('2023-1-1'), 'A', 10]
                            , [pd.Timestamp('2023-1-1'), 'B', 11]
                            , [pd.Timestamp('2023-1-2'), 'C', 12]]),
                   columns=['Date', 'Title', 'Amount'])

df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['Date', 'Title', 'Amount'], how="outer", indicator=True)
df3 = df3[df3['_merge'] == 'left_only']

print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df3) # Both 'A' rows deleted while one 'A' row is new and should be in df3
```

The output is:

```
       Date Title Amount
0 2023-01-01     A     10
1 2023-01-01     A     10
2 2023-01-01     B     11
3 2023-01-02     C     12
4 2023-01-02     D     13
5 2023-01-02     E     14
6 2023-01-03     F     15
        Date Title Amount
0 2023-01-01     A     10
1 2023-01-01     B     11
2 2023-01-02     C     12
        Date Title Amount     _merge
4 2023-01-02     D     13  left_only
5 2023-01-02     E     14  left_only
6 2023-01-03     F     15  left_only
```

With the above method, both `'A'` rows are deleted while one `'A'` row is new and thus should be in the new DataFrame.

Any ideas on what operation can be used to keep **only** the rows that in the first Dataframe **with** consideration to rows count? To give a little more information, transactions in the same day are not ordered (*no time information, only date*) and new transactions can be added multiple days in the past.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you most likely want this :

```
df3 = (
    pd.merge(df1, df2,
             left_on = [*list(df1), df1.groupby(list(df1)).cumcount()],
             right_on= [*list(df2), df2.groupby(list(df2)).cumcount()],
             how="outer", indicator=True)
        .query("_merge == 'left_only'")
        .drop(columns="key_3")
)
```

Output :

```
print(df3)

        Date Title Amount     _merge
1 2023-01-01     A     10  left_only
4 2023-01-02     D     13  left_only
5 2023-01-02     E     14  left_only
6 2023-01-03     F     15  left_only
```